# HTTP request error code 429 cannot be caught

Tags: javascript, http, fetch-api

Using [fetchApi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) I am issuing a POST request to an endpoint and catching errors like this:

```
fetch(new Request(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { ...defaultHeaders, ...headers } ,
  credentials: 'include',
  body: JSON.stringify(body)
})).then(
  // handle correct reponse
).catch(
  if (err.status === 401) {
       // handle error nicely
    } else if (err.status === 429) {
       // handle error differently
    } else {
      // handle error yet another way
    }
);
```

While 401 error is handled as expected, when the endpoint responds with 429 the code

```
else if (err.status === 429) {
       // handle error differently
    }
```

Is never executed.

EDIT1: the entire catch is never reached in case of 429

**Are 401 and 429 status codes handled differently by javascript/browsers?**
**How Can I catch 429 error and handle it my way?**

Comment: Is the `catch` executed at all? Then have you debugged whether `err.status` is *really exactly* `429`?

Comment: The catch is executed in case of 401 status code but is not executed at all in case of 429. I know it is 429 indeed because the error is logged in the JS console in the browser.

Comment: OK, so the problem is not that the `else if` isn't matching, it's that `fetch` doesn't reject the promise, right?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not with the if not matching it is indeed with something going wrong just before that, most likely promise being rejected like you say but I am not sure.

Comment: @PiotrZakrzewski Looks like fetch API does not reject  when response status is 429. Instead, you may need to handle it in `then` logic.

Comment: Playing around with http://httpstat.us, I can't get *any* status code to reject. Poking through the spec it appears that the promise is only rejected if the response's `type` is `"error"`, but in these example it's always `"cors"`. Maybe these observations will help…

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks mostly like wrong expectations. The promise will only be rejected (and hence `catch` invoked) when the response's `type` is `"error"`, which only seems to be the case for very specific, limited cases.

> [Per MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful), the `fetch()` API only rejects a promise when a *“network error is encountered, although this usually means permissions issues or similar.”* Basically `fetch()` will only reject a promise if the user is offline, or some unlikely networking error occurs, such a DNS lookup failure.

In other words, a request with a 429 response is still a successfully executed request.

> The good is news is fetch provides a simple `ok` flag that indicates whether an HTTP response’s status code is in the successful range or not.
>
> ```
> fetch("http://httpstat.us/500")
>     .then(function(response) {
>         if (!response.ok) {
>             throw Error(response.statusText);
>         }
>     })
> ```
>
> https://www.tjvantoll.com/2015/09/13/fetch-and-errors/